# is declare -A explicit declaration mandatory in associative arrays in Bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, associative-array, declare

I have defined a bash associative array without the explicit declare -A command. But I am not sure if it really is the associative array since I read somewhere without the declare -A, the array is treated as indexed array by Bash.

I tried the below code:

```
players=([tennis]=fedExpress [cricket]=buzz [football]=cr7)
echo "${players[tennis]}"
```

the o/p is: cr7  but should be fedExpress

but in geeks for geeks article, they declared an indexed array as follows:

```
ARRAYNAME=([1]=10 [2]=20 [3]=30)
```

so, w/o the declare -A, is the player's array also treated as an indexed array? or associative array?
please clarify this. I am writing an article so I have to be corroborative in what I write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is declare -A explicit declaration mandatory in associative arrays in Bash?

Yes.

> w/o the declare -A, is the player's array also treated as an indexed array? or associative array?

Indexed. You do not need us for this - use `declare -p` to inspect a variable with all the flags.

The string inside `[this]` is treated as an arithmetic expression (unless it is an associative array). Inside arithmetic expression undefined variables are equal to 0, i.e. `echo $((something))` outputs `0`, see documentation. The following with undefined variables `tennis` `cricket` and `football`:

```
 players=([tennis]=fedExpress [cricket]=buzz [football]=cr7)
```

Is just equal to:

```
players=([0]=fedExpress [0]=buzz [0]=cr7)
```

However, consider:

```
$ tennis=123
$ cricket=123*2
$ players=([tennis]=fedExpress [cricket]=buzz [football]=cr7)
$ declare -p players
declare -a players=([0]="cr7" [123]="fedExpress" [246]="buzz")
```